# Python: Concatenate two list elements to one

Tags: list, python-3.x, concatenation

I have a list with elements that looks like this:

```
rules = {'A': ['CD','CF']}
```

Now i have two different letters for example ['C'] and ['D'] that need to be combined to ['CD'] and put into a list.
The line i am using to do this is this:

```
checkC = possibleProductions[indexList] + tempC
```

However checkC gets combined to ['C', 'D'] while i need ['CD']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both of the operands are lists, each containing a single string, try:

```
checkC = [possibleProductions[indexList][0] + tempC[0]]
```

If the situation is more complicated than that, try:

```
checkC = possibleProductions[indexList] + tempC
checkC = [''.join(checkC)]
```

Comment: Looks like both are woking fine for my purpose